# Error in converting categorical variables to factor in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, decision-tree

In this [tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/12/using-decision-trees-to-predict-infant-birth-weights/), I tried to use another method for converting categorical variables to factor.

In the article, the following method is used.

```
library(MASS)
library(rpart)
cols <- c('low', 'race', 'smoke', 'ht', 'ui')
birthwt[cols] <- lapply(birthwt[cols], as.factor)
```

and I replaced the last line by

```
birthwt[cols] <- as.factor((birthwt[cols]))
```

but the result is NA all

[image]

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.factor((birthwt[cols]))` is calling `as.factor` on a list of 5 vectors. If you do that R will interpret each of those 5 vectors as the levels, and the column headers as the labels, of a factor variable, which is clearly not what you want:

```
> as.factor(birthwt[cols])
  low  race smoke    ht    ui 
 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
5 Levels: c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) ...
> labels(as.factor(birthwt[cols]))
[1] "low"   "race"  "smoke" "ht"    "ui"
```

`lapply` iterates over a list, calling the function `as.factor` on each of the vectors separately in that list. You need to do this to convert each variable separately into a factor, rather than attempting to convert the entire list into a single factor, which is what `as.factor(birthwt[cols])` does.

Comment: Sorry I got in just ahead of you [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994135/903061). Nice answer here, good explanation!